# Avro Schema. How to set type to "record" and "null" at once

Tags: null, schema, union, record, avro

I need to mix "record" type with null type in Schema.

```
"name":"specShape",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"noSpecShape",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"bpSsc",
                  "type":"null",
                  "default":null,
                  "doc":"SampleValue: null"
               },...
```

For example, for some datas specShape may be null.

So if I set type to

```
"name":"specShape",
         "type":{
            **"type":["record", "null"],**
            "name":"noSpecShape",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"bpSsc",
                  "type":"null",
                  "default":null,
                  "doc":"SampleValue: null"
               },...
```

it says

```
No type: {"type":["record","null"]...
```

But if I set whoole type to

```
"name":"specShape",
         **"type":[{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"noSpecShape",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"bpSsc",
                  "type":"null",
                  "default":null,
                  "doc":"SampleValue: null"
               }, "null"]**,...
```

it says

```
Not in union [{"type":"record"
```

How to union these two types?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You had the right idea, you just need to include `"null"` in the higher level `"type"` array instead of inside the `"fields"` array (as in your third example). This is the schema for a nullable record:

```
[
  "null",
  {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "NoSpecShape",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "null",
        "name": "bpSsc",
        "default": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can also nest it anywhere a type declaration is expected, for example inside another record:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "SpecShape",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "NoSpecShape",
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": "null",
              "name": "bpSsc",
              "default": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "name": "shape"
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON-encoded instances of this last schema would look like:

- `{"shape": null}`
- `{"shape": {"NoSpecShape": {"bpSsc": null}}}`

Comment: But now I am getting "Not in union" exception while adding record, can you help.

Comment: Added a couple sample records to the answer which should hopefully help. (Don't forget that union instances must be "wrapped" when JSON-encoded.)