# How to set type to “record” and “null” at once in Avro Schema?

Tags: json, null, apache-nifi, avro, avro-tools

I am trying to set the type to record and null at the same time. I don't know if it is possible.
Here is my input json

```
{
   "request":{
      "reqNo": null
   },
   "dataset":{
      "id":"1",
      "value":"sample"
   }
}
```

And now I am creating Avroschema using Nifi,

```
GenerateFlowFile -->> InferAvroSchema -->> AttributeToJson
```

I will get the corresponding schema

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"one",
   "namespace":"com.sixdee",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"request",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"request",
            "namespace":"",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"reqNo",
                  "type":"null"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"dataset",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"dataset",
            "namespace":"",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"id",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"value",
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and now I will validate this schema and input json using a java code. It gives success. But problem is I can't make the Request tag as null and record at the same time. For that, i refereed another example.

[Avro Schema. How to set type to "record" and "null" at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321616/avro-schema-how-to-set-type-to-record-and-null-at-once)

And I modified my Avro schema to meet my requirement of setting type to null and record at once.

Modified Avro Schema:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"one",
   "namespace":"com.sixdee",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"request",
         "type":   [
     "null", {
               "type":{
                  "type":"record",
                  "name":"request",
                  "fields":[
                     {
                        "name":"reqNo",
                        "type":"null"
                     }
                  ]
               }
          }
]
      },
      {
         "name":"dataset",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"dataset",
            "namespace":"",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"id",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"value",
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

But, while validating this schema with my input json, it fails. And I am getting an except like this.

```
org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: No type: {"type":{"type":"record","name":"request","fields":[{"name":"reqNo","type":"null"}]}}
```

I need a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Modified Avro Schema

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"one",
   "namespace":"com.sixdee",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"request",
         "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"record",
               "name":"request",
               "fields":[
                     {
                        "name":"reqNo",
                        "type":"null"
                     }
                  ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"dataset",
         "type":{
            "type":"record",
            "name":"dataset",
            "namespace":"",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"id",
                  "type":"string"
               },
               {
                  "name":"value",
                  "type":"string"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

There was an error in the schema that I used to make it Null. I recognized that error now.

```
 "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"record",
               "name":"request",
               "fields":[
                     {
                        "name":"reqNo",
                        "type":"null"
                     }
                  ]
            }
         ]
```